# Using jQuery, how can I detect when a dom element has been changed? Needs IE8+ support

Tags: jquery

All answers I see to this question are several years old or doesn't support IE8. I've read about the event "DOMNodeInserted" and "MutationObservers" which are either old or have no IE8 support.

What's the standard way in jQuery to detect if a DOM element has been changed/updated/remove etc?

What i want to achieve:

```
$('#element').whenThisElementChangesInAnyWay(function(){
    doStuff();
});
```

**EDIT: It needs to support IE8+**

Answer (score 2):

To support chrome/ff:

```
$("#element").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    //do stuff here
});
```

To Support IE:

```
$("#element").on("propertychange", function() {
    //do stuff here
});
```

So, it would be better using altogether:

```
$("#element").on("DOMSubtreeModified propertychange", function() {
        //do stuff here
    });
```

Comment: Lol I didnt know this exists, awesome!

Comment: @C-link Nepal: After a quick google search it doesn't seem it's IE8 compatible. Or?